# How to use REGEXP_SUBSTR or REGEXP_EXTRACT in MySQL Workbench with database hosted on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I am working on a MYSQL database which is hosted on Google Cloud SQL. I am working through MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE.

I want to get a substring of the `element_name` column in the table `p0999_pakbon` in the schema `projects`.
Element names are like "LVLS 45 Beam 1" and "SPANO 18 Stud 1". I want to get: "LVLS 45" and "SPANO 18"

In an old copy of the database which is hosted on my local machine, the following code works perfectly:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(pp.element_name, "[A-Z]+[:space:][0-9]+")
FROM projects.p0999_pakbon pp
```

This is because `REGEXP_SUBSTR` is the standard function to get a substring in MySQL.
However, this code does not work in my database hosted in Google Cloud SQL. On this page https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract I seem to read that Google Cloud SQL uses `REGEXP__EXTRACT` instead. But also when I try the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(pp.element_name, "[A-Z]+[:space:][0-9]+")
FROM projects.p0999_pakbon pp
```

It does not work. It also doesn't work when I change the regex to a very simple one like "A".

I am getting these errors:
*FUNCTION projects.REGEXP_SUBSTR does not exist*
*FUNCTION projects.REGEXP_EXTRACT does not exist*

When I type the arguments in the wrong format, I get this error message:
*Incorrect parameters in the call to stored fucntion 'REGEXP_EXTRACT'*

Does anybody know how to solve my problem? Or maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: The real question is what version of MySQL Google has.  Workbench is just a UI; it's version is irrelevant.  I suspect they do not use MySQL 8.0, which is one place to find those functions.  (A recent version of MariaDB is the other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the first two words, you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here, which should work on most versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('LVLS 45 Beam 1', ' ', 2) AS item
FROM yourTable;
```

If you also need to assert that the first term contains capitals, with the second digits, you could use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 'LVLS 45 Beam 1' REGEXP '^[A-Z]+ [0-9]+'
         THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX('LVLS 45 Beam 1', ' ', 2)
         ELSE 'no match' END AS item
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Fantastic! Of course, it remains an interesting question whether you can use REGEXP_SUBSTR or REGEXP_EXTRACT in MySQL x Google Cloud SQL, because there might be situations where this workaround doesn't work. But for me, it solves the problem!

Comment: @Josien Yes, that's a good question.  If Google Cloud SQL really supports the full MySQL 8+ engine, then in fact `REGEXP_SUBSTR` should be working.